# Fade out and replace a div multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

Okay. So I have a div and I figured out how to fade it out and replace it with certain text.

However, I want the second text that fades in to also fade out and a third div to fade in. After that, I want the fourth div to replace the third and so on.

How exactly can I go about achieving this?

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dubr/1/

```
<div id="foo">test</div>

$('#foo').delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function(){
var div = $("<div id='foo'>test2</div>").hide();
$(this).replaceWith(div);
$('#foo').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this recursive function

```js
function fadeMessages(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) return;
    $('#foo').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#foo").html(arr[0]).hide().fadeIn("slow", function() {
            arr.shift();
            fadeMessages(arr);
        });
    });
}

fadeMessages(["good", "morning", "to", "everyone", "<img src='https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_4892c96bf7cb_128.png'><br><button> OK </button>"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo">test</div>
```

Comment: And if I want the final part to include an image and a button, how could I achieve that?

Your solution works for text, but I should've been clearer in the question.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an image a button (basically any html you want), and remove the unnecessary`var div =` (thanks for pointing it out @Dmitriy Demir)

Comment: Cheers. Thank you for this efficient solution. Made me go start a tutorial series on recursive functions!

Comment: Another query I have is if I want to delay the execution a little bit, and make the <div id="foo">test</div> to stay on screen longer, how would that work?

I tried setTimeout but that didn't work. Or I'm doing it wrong.


also, test and good slide up but everything else fades in.

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. I added .delay before the .fadeout and .fadein

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```js
function changeHtml(html, callback) {

$('#foo').fadeOut("slow", function(){
   $(this).html(html);
   $(this).fadeIn("slow", callback);
});
  
}

changeHtml('test2', function() {
  changeHtml('test3', function() {
     changeHtml('<img src=""/>', function() {
  
     });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">test</div>
```

Comment: I want to replace the test2 with some more text and then I want to replace that text with an image and that image will be the final div which stays on screen. I'm not really sure how exactly I could achieve that.